# How can I specify the image for Facebook share or like?

Tags: facebook, images, like

Is there a way I can make one of the images on a website more likely to be posted with a Facebook like or recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [like button documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/path/to/image.png" />
```

See that page for several other tags you can also set.

Comment: OK thanks, but I understand that in order for this to work I have to use all six required meta tags, is this correct? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Update 2015. To what I understand, Facebook has changed the link to the document. Now you can find the tags on [Facebook Debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools)